# SLURM job use IP of the node

Tags: ip, slurm

I have 3 workers/nodes and each worker is connected to internet (worker1 ip: x.x.x.101, worker2 ip: x.x.x.102, worker3 ip: x.x.x.103)

How can I say to the job, running on worker3, to use the worker3 ip (x.x.x.103) for internet connection to an external server? For the worker job I can use --nodelist=worker3, for the ip?

Thank you!